# Rescaling standardised parameters fitted through gradient descent

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, gradient-descent

As a learning exercise, I have been implementing multiple linear regression from scratch using gradient descent to fit the parameters.

Following the conventional approach to the algorithm, I have managed to dramatically speed up the convergence by standardising all of the features such that they have mean 0 and standard deviation 1 according to the formula:
$$x' = \frac{x-\bar{x}}\sigma$$

My question is: is there an easy approach to rescale the resulting intercept and parameters such that they can take a vector of feature values and predict a value for Y all in the original scale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have standardized each feature of $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ like this
$$x_i' = \frac{x_i-\bar{x_i}}{\sigma_{i}}$$
Your resulting regression is
$$
\frac{y-\bar{y}}{\sigma_{y}} = \alpha_0+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i\cdot x_i' =\alpha_0+
\sum_{i=1}^{n}
\alpha_i
\frac{x_i-\bar{x_i}}{\sigma_{i}}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i\frac{x_i}{\sigma_{i}}+\left(\alpha_0-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i\frac{\bar{x_i}}{\sigma_{i}}\right)$$
Which implies
$$
y = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sigma_{y}\alpha_i\frac{x_i}{\sigma_{i}}+\sigma_y\left(\alpha_0-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i\frac{\bar{x_i}}{\sigma_{i}}\right)+\bar{y}$$

Thus, you can use $\beta_i=\frac{\sigma_y\alpha_i}{\sigma_i}$ and intercept 
$\beta_0=\sigma_y\left(\alpha_0-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i\frac{\bar{x_i}}{\sigma_{i}}\right)+\bar{y}$

Comment: This makes intuitive sense to me, but doesn't seem to be working. If I compare the parameters I fit with the standardised data against those fitted on the raw data (which yield an identical R-squared value, suggesting they are indeed equivalent), the standardised parameters are all between 2 and 8 times larger than their unstandardised counterparts. All of the standard deviations, meanwhile, are around 50-200, which scale the parameters by far too much when I follow your suggestion. Any ideas? Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you standardize $y$, too?

Comment: I did. Was that not necessary?

Comment: I have modified my answer according to your assumption that you have normalized the $y$ data.

Comment: Many thanks for the help. For anyone else reading, since posting the above comment I modified my code to fit the model without standardising $y$. While this produced the desired result, convergence seems to be far quicker with $y$ standardised.